# How to disable GtkColorButton?

Tags: c, gtk

So I'm using a GtkColorButton as a color sampler (to show what color is currently being used). For complicated reasons I don't want the selection options to come up when I click on it (I have another way of picking the color). Is there a way to disable this functionality? In other words, I just want the GtkColorButton to sit there so I can change the color shown on it through gtk_color_button_set_color (), but I don't want it to be able to be clicked.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

`gtk_widget_set_sensitive (widget, FALSE);` will disable the widget, but it'll still show the colour

Comment: This does not work, I don't think the method exists in the documentation anymore...

Comment: sorry, I meant gtk_widget_set_sensitive (widget, FALSE); Have edited.